# Get first N occurances of uniq lines, not only one

Tags: bash, uniq

i have file with rows where are two fields separated by whitespace:

```
fieldA fieldX
fieldB fieldX
fieldC fieldX
fieldD fieldX
fieldE fieldX
fieldA fieldY
fieldB fieldY
fieldC fieldY
```

I need to get first N rows of type in second column. What I do is 
`sort -k2 | uniq -f1 --all-repeated=prepend | grep "^$" -A3` 
which should work but `uniq -f1` gives me something different than `uniq -f1 --all-repeated=prepend`. Do I understand it correctly that prepend should only add emtpy line before unique chunk?

Or is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea using `awk`:

```
awk -v maxlines=<N> ' ++count[$2] <= maxlines { print } '
```

That will not require sorting the file (but you could still sort it first if there are other reasons you want to...).

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not quite right about prepend.

`prepend` tells `uniq` to print a blank file before each chunk of **duplicates**. Remember that by adding the `--all-repeated` option you're telling `uniq` to print only lines which have duplicates i.e. those that occur more than once. It will not print out lines that occur **exactly** once, like `uniq -f1` does.

For example, if you add another line to your file, say, `fieldA fieldZ`, it will not be output if you have the `--all-repeated` option because it only occurs in the file once.